# Marked Item Read in Listview React Native

Tags: listview, react-native

Below are the codes of my listview, basically it's a list of news:

```
 <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={this.changeTextColor.bind(this)}
    underlayColor={"#E8E8E8"}
    style={[styles.button]}>
    <View style={styles.news_item}>
      <Text style={[styles.news_item_text,{color:this.state.color}]}>{news.title}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>

changeTextColor(){
   console.log('clicked');
   this.setState({
    color: '#ffffff'
    });
 }
```

What I tried to do is that after clicking a news item, the text color will be changed via changeTextColor().

Somehow, the color won't change, any idea?

Comment: does `clicked` appear in the console? do you have a `shouldComponentUpdate` method?

Comment: don't use `.bind(this)`. Please read this article [Don't Use Bind When Passing Props](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/)

Comment: even if this did work, I would expect that clicking any one list item would change all list items to white since they all map to {this.state.color}. I think you'll need to update your list's datasource to add a "isRead" and then use that to decide which color to render.

Comment: You're right. I forgot that setState will refresh all items..

Comment: @ChrisGeirman btw, how can I change the news property via onPress. For example, I try to set the news.isRead = true, but it has no effect.

Comment: So here's how it would basically work. 1) when rendering the list, use a ternary to decide which background color to apply based on `isRead` 2) you'd add a `handlePress(key)` function and pass the id/key of the news article. 3) in handlePress, you'd modify the object used to generate the listview, find the specific object within that (by key) then add an `isRead: true` to it (e.g. `Object.assign(obj, {isRead: true}`). 4) after that, I assume you'll want to navigate somewhere so you can pop that onto the navigation stack. I'm not sure what you're doing here, but when you re-render it should wk

Comment: I don't have time right now to create a demo for you, but if you want to setup the basics on rnplay.org I'll help you get it working.

Comment: also, see this for conditionally applying the background color http://reactpatterns.com/#Conditional Rendering

Comment: @ChrisGeirman Please kindly review my codes https://rnplay.org/apps/TGtjLw  (index.android.js)

Answer (score 0):

an example of what you're trying to do can be found here...
https://github.com/VctrySam/Pokemon/blob/master/app/components/pokedex.js

Here's a demo video. Look at the Pokedex portion around second 29
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RG6FFL2ny3s&feature=youtu.be

here he defines his listview as such ([see actual code](https://github.com/VctrySam/Pokemon/blob/master/app/components/pokedex.js#L210-L214))...

```
  <ListView
      bounce = {false}
      style = {{flex:1, marginBottom:30 }}
      dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow = {(rowData) => this.balls(rowData)} />
```

Notice that `renderRow`calls `this.balls(rowData)` passing in the rowData, which is used to build the view depending on whether the row (or ball) is selected or not. ([See actual code](https://github.com/VctrySam/Pokemon/blob/master/app/components/pokedex.js#L154-L186))

```
  balls(x){
      if(!x.selected){
        return(
          <View>
             // row definition if NOT selected
          </View>
        )
      } else {
        return(
          <View>
             // row definition if IS selected
          </View>
        )
      }
  }
```